# Delays in .net app when connecting to oracle db using Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: asp.net, oracle, trace

I have a .net desktop app that connects to an oracle database.  At times, there are very noticable delays.

I ran a trace on the code, and it was always in the DataReader.Read().

I turned on sql tracing, and found the following, which corresponds to the delays I'm seeing:

```
(2128) [23-MAR-2010 13:00:07:310] nsprecv: reading from transport...
(2128) [23-MAR-2010 13:00:07:310] nttrd: entry
(2128) [23-MAR-2010 13:00:24:655] nttrd: socket 676 had bytes read=2047
(2128) [23-MAR-2010 13:00:24:655] nttrd: exit
(2128) [23-MAR-2010 13:00:24:655] nsprecv: 2047 bytes from transport
```

There's about a 14 second pause in there.

I'm pretty sure that there's not a problem in the code, but not sure where to look at next.  Is there anyone out there with experience with oracle trace that can explain what's going on?

Comment: What does your DB look like?  Is there a large amount of records?  Is it properly indexed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not a db problem.  But yes, it's been reviewed by at least 2 DBAs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you traced your networks? If you have problem in your network you could run in to this.

Comment: According to the network guys, it's not a network problem.  sqlplus from the command line seems to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried doing a network trace when your application is running? To see its output. 

And if you don't see an issue with the network then I would add a break-point at the bottom of stack and check if it is writing to the socket. I would use Windbg to set a break-point  and debug.

If you have issues in setting break-point, do respond.